# How to convert a string object to jsonobject in multithreaded environment in java

Tags: java, json, multithreading

i am using net.sf.json.JSONSerializer to convert a java.lang.String object to net.sf.json.JSONObject .But this JSONSerializer  internally use the java.util.HashMap which is not recommended to use in multithreaded environment.Because HashMap  is not Synchronized it self ,so in threaded environment it is possible that concurrent access to the map corrupted the internal data resulting in unpredictable behaviour like infinite loop which cause a thread got stuck,which i am currently facing in my project.

so please suggest the appropriate class can be used to convert a String object to JSONObject in multithreaded environment.

Comment: I hope you are not about to convert to json a shared oject, if so you can lock it and serialize it releasing the object when you're done... nothing more, nothing less..

Comment: I think your question is how can you make JSONObject thread-safe rather than how you can convert a String to a JSONObject in a thread-safe fashion?

Comment: My question is how can i convert a String into a JSONObject in a thread-safe fashion.In my project i am using JSONSerializer in multithreaded environment for convert String into JSONObject ,which internally using HashMap cause a thread getting stuck(HashMap is not synchronized,which can cause a infinite loop in multithreaded environment and the thread get stuck).u can refer this URL to know the HashMap related issue: javabypatel.blogspot.in/2016/01/infinite-loop-in-hashmap.html